# Opening Excel file in Java using POI results in error InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have seen several posts dealing with this error, but none have addressed the specific problem I am encountering.

Here is the code I am testing with.

```
public class CicTemplateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new CicTemplateTest().process();
        System.out.println("DONE xlsx");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void process() throws Exception
{
    String inputFileName = "Test.xlsx";

    String folder = "/Temp3/formaterror/";

    File file = new File(folder + inputFileName);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);  // line where error occurred

    OutputStream out2 =  new FileOutputStream(new File(folder+"JunkFile.xlsx"));

    wb.write(out2); 
    out2.flush(); 
    out2.close();
}
```

}

Here is the error I get.

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:274)
at com.aquent.sdc.jeffk.poiftest.CicTemplateTest.process(CicTemplateTest.java:41)
at com.aquent.sdc.jeffk.poiftest.CicTemplateTest.main(CicTemplateTest.java:25)
```

The file in question is not an XLS file.  It seems to be a weird form of an XLSX file.  I wish I could share the file, but I can't as the data is proprietary.  I've had to unzip XLSX files in the past and am somewhat familiar with the contents.  When I unzip this file the contents do not look normal.

[List of files in XLSX file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqn9.jpg)

There are no XML files in there. I've examined every file in the XLSX and they are all binary files.  No text file, no XML files.  It just doesn't look like a normal XLSX file at all.

It opens fine in Excel, and if I save it, the saved file is a normal XLSX file and sample code works fine.

We get about 1000 users per year submitting these files, and about 15% come to us in this format.  I think most of the files with the format problem are from outside of North America.

I have tried reading the file using POI ver 3.9 and 3.14 and get the same error.

I have 2 questions.

How are users creating these files?

How can I get my app to open these files?

Comment: Could it be an XLS file saved with the wrong ending? Could you try to use HSSFWorkbook on it and see what happens?

Comment: I checked, It is not an XLS file, also it is not an XLSB file.

Comment: Have you considered using TIKA for finding more information about the file? https://tika.apache.org/1.1/detection.html

Comment: Thanks for TIKA suggestion.  TIKA reported type as application/x-tika-msoffice.  For a bonafide XLSX file it returned type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: What happens if you are opening those files using Excel? I bet a password is required. According to your 7-Zip screen shot, the files are protected by encryption as described in [Protect an Excel file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Protect-an-Excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599). So you need the password an [XML-based formats - Decryption](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Decryption) to open them using apache poi.

Comment: Significant portions of the Excel file are password protected, but the file can be opened and data can be entered without the password.  When I open the file in Excel and save it, without using any password, it saves in the "normal" format as a bunch of zipped XML files.

Comment: According to your 7-Zip screen-shot, the `Test.xlsx` definitely is an encrypted workbook.

Comment: @AxelRichter I agree.  Thanks for pointing out the likely problem and for the links.  I am attempting to get the password to confirm this.